# Add sticky bit on found directories in ansible

Tags: ansible

```yaml
---
- name: world writable directories
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: sction 3.5.7
      command: find / -perm -0002 -a ! -perm 1000 -type d -print
      register: output
    - debug: var=output.stdout_lines
```

Using the above code I am getting some directories in the output. I need to set the sticky bit to all found directories. Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is missing a sample output of your registered data structure. For future questions please see [How to create an MCVE](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add-up to @P... answer: there is no ansible equivalent to your find command using modules so using `shell`/`command` has no workaround I know.

Meanwhile, you can set the sticky bit using the [`file` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html). You should also make sure your `command` task does not return a `changed` status since it only queries for information.

Here is a complete illustration playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: World writable directories
  hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:

    - name: Find world writable directories
      command: find / -perm -0002 -a ! -perm 1000 -type d -print
      register: output
      changed_when: false

    - name: Set sticky bit on found directories
      file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        mode: "+t"
      loop: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Below task would print **and** add sticky bit to the world writable directories. This is just extension of your original `find` command by using `exec` to execute the `chmod` command on the `{}`(placeholder for the find output)

```yaml
  - name: "Find and add sticky bit to world writable directories"
    shell: find / -perm -0002 -a ! -perm 1000 -type d -print -exec chmod  +t {} + ||true
    register: output
    
  - debug: var=output.stdout_lines
```

If you do not wish to do print and sticky bit addition in single task, you may use:

```yaml
  - name: "Find the world writable directories"
    shell: find / -perm -0002 -a ! -perm 1000 -type d -print ||true
    register: output

  - name: "Add sticky bit to world writable directories"
    shell: chmod +t "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
```